# Extract text in parentheses from an R data.frame column into two or more new columns

Tags: r

I have a column in my dataframe titled "Indicator.Name" and the attributes look like "Adolescent fertility rate (births per 1,000 women ages 15-19)" or "Adults (ages 15+) and children (ages 0-14) newly infected with HIV.."

I am trying to split this column into two columns with one containing the part of the string not within parentheses and another containing the strings which are within the parentheses. Any help would be great!

Comment: Welcome to SO! pleas post your data so we can run code with. Paste the output from `dput(your_dataframe)`.

Answer (score 0):

To create the column with the parts of the string within parentheses we can `sapply` a `str_extract_all` operation, making sure to `paste0` the results together if there are more than one expression in parentheses:

```
library(stringr)
df$New1 <- sapply(str_extract_all(df$Indicator.Name, "(?<=\\()[^)(]+(?=\\))"), paste0, collapse =",")
```

To create the column with the parts of the string *not* within parentheses, we can remove anything inside an opening parenthesis `\\(`and a closing parenthesis `\\)`using `gsub`:

```
df$New2 <- gsub("\\([^)(]+\\)", "", df$Indicator.Name)
```

Result:

```
df 
                                                        Indicator.Name                              New1                                            New2
1        Adolescent fertility rate (births per 1,000 women ages 15-19) births per 1,000 women ages 15-19                      Adolescent fertility rate 
2 Adults (ages 15+) and children (ages 0-14) newly infected with HIV..                ages 15+,ages 0-14 Adults  and children  newly infected with HIV..
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Indicator.Name = c("Adolescent fertility rate (births per 1,000 women ages 15-19)",
                     "Adults (ages 15+) and children (ages 0-14) newly infected with HIV.."))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem and data correctly one possible solution within the tidyverse is:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rebus)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
# sample data extracted from your question
df <- dplyr::tibble(Indicator.Name = c("Adolescent fertility rate (births per 1,000 women ages 15-19)",
                                       "Adults (ages 15+) and children (ages 0-14) newly infected with HIV.."))

# pattern of anything between an opening and closing parenthesis
pattern <- OPEN_PAREN %R% ".*?" %R% CLOSE_PAREN

# extracting the values inside parenthesis => result object is a list with differing lengths
stringr::str_extract_all(df$Indicator.Name, pattern)

[[1]] # one value for first vector value
[1] "(births per 1,000 women ages 15-19)"

[[2]] # two results for second vector value
[1] "(ages 15+)"  "(ages 0-14)"


# how the differing lenghts can be handled to get to rectangular data shape (table with no nesting)
df %>%
  # make a new colum of the data inside and outside of the parenthesis
  dplyr::transmute(INSIDE = stringr::str_extract_all(Indicator.Name, pattern), 
                OUTSIDE = stringr::str_remove_all(Indicator.Name, pattern)) %>% 
  # the INSIDE colum is nested as it has more then one value per original data row (see first use of pattern extraction) so we have to unnest to get back to rectangular data
  tidyr::unnest(INSIDE)

INSIDE                              OUTSIDE                                          
<chr>                               <chr>                                            
1 (births per 1,000 women ages 15-19) "Adolescent fertility rate "                     
2 (ages 15+)                          "Adults  and children  newly infected with HIV.."
3 (ages 0-14)                         "Adults  and children  newly infected with HIV.."

# same as before but with aditional code to colapse the data into two rows
df %>%
  # make a new colum of the data inside and outside of the parenthesis
  dplyr::transmute(INSIDE = stringr::str_extract_all(Indicator.Name, pattern), 
                OUTSIDE = stringr::str_remove_all(Indicator.Name, pattern)) %>% 
  tidyr::unnest(INSIDE) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(OUTSIDE) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(INSIDE = paste(INSIDE, collapse = ", ")) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup()

OUTSIDE                                           INSIDE                             
<chr>                                             <chr>                              
1 "Adolescent fertility rate "                      (births per 1,000 women ages 15-19)
2 "Adults  and children  newly infected with HIV.." (ages 15+), (ages 0-14)
```

Comment: Thank you for this! This code results in 3 rows as shown above (2 and 3 coming from the same original row). Is it possible to have 2 and 3 in the same row? 
I am very new to R and I appreciate your help!

Comment: @Omar I included a new section in the answer which extends on initial answer, collapsing it into two rows instead of 3